# OpenGL Rendering Context Produces "opcode of failed request 152 (GLX)" (Mesa 8.0 - OpenGL 3.0, Linux)

Tags: c, xlib, opengl-3, glx

This one is a huge issue: first off, while I know a *little* bit about the XLib API, I wanted to test and make sure I could actually create an OpenGL rendering context (3.0) before I did anything, thus I just copied and pasted some test code and ran it.

**When I run the code, my output is as follows:**

```
GLX_ARB_get_proc_address GLX_ARB_multisample GLX_EXT_import_context GLX_EXT_visual_info GLX_EXT_visual_rating GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent GLX_MESA_swap_control GLX_OML_swap_method GLX_OML_sync_control GLX_SGI_make_current_read GLX_SGI_swap_control GLX_SGI_video_sync GLX_SGIS_multisample GLX_SGIX_fbconfig GLX_SGIX_pbuffer GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap 
Getting framebuffer config
Getting XVisualInfo
Creating colormap
Creating window
Mapping window
Creating context
X Error of failed request:  BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  152 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  34 ()
  Serial number of failed request:  27
  Current serial number in output stream:  26
```

**Further more, a subsequent call to `glxinfo` produces**

```
name of display: :0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
server glx vendor string: SGI
server glx version string: 1.4
server glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_import_context, GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, 
    GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, 
    GLX_OML_swap_method, GLX_SGI_swap_control, GLX_SGIS_multisample, 
    GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, 
    GLX_INTEL_swap_event
client glx vendor string: Mesa Project and SGI
client glx version string: 1.4
client glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_create_context, GLX_ARB_create_context_profile, 
    GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_import_context, 
    GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, 
    GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, 
    GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_MESA_swap_control, 
    GLX_OML_swap_method, GLX_OML_sync_control, GLX_SGI_make_current_read, 
    GLX_SGI_swap_control, GLX_SGI_video_sync, GLX_SGIS_multisample, 
    GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, 
    GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_INTEL_swap_event
GLX version: 1.4
GLX extensions:
    GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_import_context, 
    GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, 
    GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_MESA_swap_control, 
    GLX_OML_swap_method, GLX_OML_sync_control, GLX_SGI_make_current_read, 
    GLX_SGI_swap_control, GLX_SGI_video_sync, GLX_SGIS_multisample, 
    GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, 
    GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap
OpenGL vendor string: Tungsten Graphics, Inc
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Sandybridge Mobile 
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 8.0
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL extensions:
    GL_ARB_multisample, GL_EXT_abgr, GL_EXT_bgra, GL_EXT_blend_color, 
    GL_EXT_blend_minmax, GL_EXT_blend_subtract, GL_EXT_copy_texture, 
    GL_EXT_polygon_offset, GL_EXT_subtexture, GL_EXT_texture_object, 
    GL_EXT_vertex_array, GL_EXT_compiled_vertex_array, GL_EXT_texture, 
    GL_EXT_texture3D, GL_IBM_rasterpos_clip, GL_ARB_point_parameters, 
    GL_EXT_draw_range_elements, GL_EXT_packed_pixels, GL_EXT_point_parameters, 
    GL_EXT_rescale_normal, GL_EXT_separate_specular_color, 
    GL_EXT_texture_edge_clamp, GL_SGIS_generate_mipmap, 
    GL_SGIS_texture_border_clamp, GL_SGIS_texture_edge_clamp, 
    GL_SGIS_texture_lod, GL_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, GL_ARB_multitexture, 
    GL_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, GL_IBM_multimode_draw_arrays, 
    GL_IBM_texture_mirrored_repeat, GL_3DFX_texture_compression_FXT1, 
    GL_ARB_texture_cube_map, GL_ARB_texture_env_add, GL_ARB_transpose_matrix, 
    GL_EXT_blend_func_separate, GL_EXT_fog_coord, GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays, 
    GL_EXT_secondary_color, GL_EXT_texture_env_add, 
    GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic, GL_EXT_texture_lod_bias, 
    GL_INGR_blend_func_separate, GL_NV_blend_square, GL_NV_light_max_exponent, 
    GL_NV_texgen_reflection, GL_NV_texture_env_combine4, 
    GL_SUN_multi_draw_arrays, GL_ARB_texture_border_clamp, 
    GL_ARB_texture_compression, GL_EXT_framebuffer_object, 
    GL_EXT_texture_env_combine, GL_EXT_texture_env_dot3, GL_MESA_window_pos, 
    GL_NV_packed_depth_stencil, GL_NV_texture_rectangle, GL_NV_vertex_program, 
    GL_ARB_depth_texture, GL_ARB_occlusion_query, GL_ARB_shadow, 
    GL_ARB_texture_env_combine, GL_ARB_texture_env_crossbar, 
    GL_ARB_texture_env_dot3, GL_ARB_texture_mirrored_repeat, 
    GL_ARB_window_pos, GL_ATI_envmap_bumpmap, GL_EXT_stencil_two_side, 
    GL_EXT_texture_cube_map, GL_NV_depth_clamp, GL_NV_vertex_program1_1, 
    GL_APPLE_packed_pixels, GL_APPLE_vertex_array_object, GL_ARB_draw_buffers, 
    GL_ARB_fragment_program, GL_ARB_fragment_shader, GL_ARB_shader_objects, 
    GL_ARB_vertex_program, GL_ARB_vertex_shader, GL_ATI_draw_buffers, 
    GL_ATI_texture_env_combine3, GL_ATI_texture_float, GL_EXT_shadow_funcs, 
    GL_EXT_stencil_wrap, GL_MESA_pack_invert, GL_MESA_ycbcr_texture, 
    GL_ARB_depth_clamp, GL_ARB_fragment_program_shadow, 
    GL_ARB_half_float_pixel, GL_ARB_point_sprite, GL_ARB_shading_language_100, 
    GL_ARB_sync, GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two, GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object, 
    GL_ATI_blend_equation_separate, GL_EXT_blend_equation_separate, 
    GL_OES_read_format, GL_ARB_color_buffer_float, GL_ARB_pixel_buffer_object, 
    GL_ARB_texture_compression_rgtc, GL_ARB_texture_float, 
    GL_ARB_texture_rectangle, GL_EXT_packed_float, GL_EXT_pixel_buffer_object, 
    GL_EXT_texture_compression_rgtc, GL_EXT_texture_rectangle, 
    GL_EXT_texture_sRGB, GL_EXT_texture_shared_exponent, 
    GL_ARB_framebuffer_object, GL_EXT_framebuffer_blit, 
    GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample, GL_EXT_packed_depth_stencil, 
    GL_APPLE_object_purgeable, GL_ARB_vertex_array_object, 
    GL_ATI_separate_stencil, GL_EXT_draw_buffers2, 
    GL_EXT_gpu_program_parameters, GL_EXT_texture_array, 
    GL_EXT_texture_integer, GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode, GL_EXT_timer_query, 
    GL_OES_EGL_image, GL_MESA_texture_array, GL_ARB_copy_buffer, 
    GL_ARB_depth_buffer_float, GL_ARB_half_float_vertex, 
    GL_ARB_map_buffer_range, GL_ARB_texture_rg, GL_ARB_texture_swizzle, 
    GL_ARB_vertex_array_bgra, GL_EXT_separate_shader_objects, 
    GL_EXT_texture_swizzle, GL_EXT_vertex_array_bgra, 
    GL_NV_conditional_render, GL_ARB_ES2_compatibility, 
    GL_ARB_draw_elements_base_vertex, GL_ARB_explicit_attrib_location, 
    GL_ARB_fragment_coord_conventions, GL_ARB_provoking_vertex, 
    GL_ARB_sampler_objects, GL_ARB_seamless_cube_map, 
    GL_ARB_shader_texture_lod, GL_EXT_provoking_vertex, GL_EXT_texture_snorm, 
    GL_MESA_texture_signed_rgba, GL_ARB_robustness, GL_EXT_transform_feedback

32 GLX Visuals
    visual  x   bf lv rg d st  colorbuffer  sr ax dp st accumbuffer  ms  cav
  id dep cl sp  sz l  ci b ro  r  g  b  a F gb bf th cl  r  g  b  a ns b eat
```

According to this specification, my could should work - correct? If not, is there anything I can do about this to change it? Any forum post I've read about having issues like this has just been usually due to people who lack the proper implementations of OpenGL 3.x when trying to initialize context, which results in them having a similar output to the code I've tested.

I've also searched for various X11 packages for my distribution to see whether or not I may or may not be missing something by some off chance. Of course, this was futile as anything I *did* end up installing/changing either made things worse, or just plain didn't work.

**xorg.conf**

```
Section "Module"
    SubSection  "extmod"
       Option    "omit xfree86-dga"
    EndSubSection
    Load    "i2c"
    Load    "ddc"
    Load    "vbe"
    Load    "dri"
    Load    "glx"
    Load    "synaptics"
    Load    "drm"
EndSection

Section "ServerFlags"
     Option    "AllowMouseOpenFail"    "true"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier    "Generic Monitor"
    VertRefresh    43 - 60
    HorizSync      28 - 80
EndSection


Section "Device"

    Identifier  "SabayonVga0"
    Driver      "intel"
    #BusID    "PCI:00:02"
    #Option "RenderAccel" "on"
    #Option "XAANoOffscreenPixmaps"
    #Option "BusType" "PCI"
    #Option "ColorTiling" "on"
    #Option "EnablePageFlip" "on"
    # UseEvents is causing segmentation faults with
    # NVIDIA 6xxx, 7xxx and >=275.xx.xx drivers
    #Option "UseEvents" "True"
    Option "LogoPath" "/usr/share/backgrounds/sabayonlinux-nvidia.png"

EndSection



Section "Screen"

    Identifier    "Screen 0"
    Device        "SabayonVga0"
    Monitor       "Generic Monitor"
    Option       "AddARGBGLXVisuals" "true"

    DefaultDepth 24

    SubSection "Display"
        Depth       8
        ViewPort    0 0
        #Modes      "1024x768" "800x600" "640x480"
    EndSubsection

    SubSection "Display"
        Depth           16
        ViewPort        0 0
        #Modes      "1024x768" "800x600" "640x480"
    EndSubsection

    SubSection "Display"
        Depth           24
        ViewPort        0 0
        #Modes      "1024x768" "800x600" "640x480"
    EndSubsection

EndSection


Section "DRI"
    Mode 0666
EndSection

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier   "Main Layout"
    Screen 0    "Screen 0"
EndSection

Section "Extensions"
   #Option "Composite" "Enable"
EndSection
```

**Executed Code**

```
#include <GL/glx.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define GLX_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION_ARB       0x2091
#define GLX_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION_ARB       0x2092
typedef GLXContext (*glXCreateContextAttribsARBProc)(Display*, GLXFBConfig, GLXContext, Bool, const int*);

int main (int argc, char ** argv)
{
    Display *display = XOpenDisplay(0);

    glXCreateContextAttribsARBProc glXCreateContextAttribsARB = NULL;

    const char *extensions = glXQueryExtensionsString(display, DefaultScreen(display));
    std::cout << extensions << std::endl;

    static int visual_attribs[] =
    {
        GLX_RENDER_TYPE, GLX_RGBA_BIT,
        GLX_DRAWABLE_TYPE, GLX_WINDOW_BIT,
        GLX_DOUBLEBUFFER, true,
        GLX_RED_SIZE, 1,
        GLX_GREEN_SIZE, 1,
        GLX_BLUE_SIZE, 1,
        None
     };

    std::cout << "Getting framebuffer config" << std::endl;
    int fbcount;
    GLXFBConfig *fbc = glXChooseFBConfig(display, DefaultScreen(display), visual_attribs, &fbcount);
    if (!fbc)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to retrieve a framebuffer config" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    std::cout << "Getting XVisualInfo" << std::endl;
    XVisualInfo *vi = glXGetVisualFromFBConfig(display, fbc[0]);

    XSetWindowAttributes swa;
    std::cout << "Creating colormap" << std::endl;
    swa.colormap = XCreateColormap(display, RootWindow(display, vi->screen), vi->visual, AllocNone);
    swa.border_pixel = 0;
    swa.event_mask = StructureNotifyMask;

    std::cout << "Creating window" << std::endl;
    Window win = XCreateWindow(display, RootWindow(display, vi->screen), 0, 0, 100, 100, 0, vi->depth, InputOutput, vi->visual, CWBorderPixel|CWColormap|CWEventMask, &swa);
    if (!win)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to create window." << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    std::cout << "Mapping window" << std::endl;
    XMapWindow(display, win);

    // Create an oldstyle context first, to get the correct function pointer for glXCreateContextAttribsARB
    GLXContext ctx_old = glXCreateContext(display, vi, 0, GL_TRUE);
    glXCreateContextAttribsARB =  (glXCreateContextAttribsARBProc)glXGetProcAddress((const GLubyte*)"glXCreateContextAttribsARB");
    glXMakeCurrent(display, 0, 0);
    glXDestroyContext(display, ctx_old);

    if (glXCreateContextAttribsARB == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "glXCreateContextAttribsARB entry point not found. Aborting." << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    static int context_attribs[] =
    {
        GLX_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION_ARB, 3,
        GLX_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION_ARB, 0,
        None
    };

    std::cout << "Creating context" << std::endl;
    GLXContext ctx = glXCreateContextAttribsARB(display, fbc[0], NULL, true, context_attribs);
    if (!ctx)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to create GL3 context." << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    std::cout << "Making context current" << std::endl;
    glXMakeCurrent(display, win, ctx);

        glClearColor (0, 0.5, 1, 1);
        glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glXSwapBuffers (display, win);

        sleep(1);

        glClearColor (1, 0.5, 0, 1);
        glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glXSwapBuffers (display, win);

        sleep(1);

    ctx = glXGetCurrentContext();
    glXMakeCurrent(display, 0, 0);
    glXDestroyContext(display, ctx);
}
```

I'm pretty stumped as to how this could be happening. Could someone please provide some insight and/or solution to this issue?

Comment: For reference: This is on the OpenGL wiki: http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Tutorial:_OpenGL_3.0_Context_Creation_(GLX)

Comment: @datenwolf That's an empty wiki page :)

Comment: @VJovic: If you click the link, Stack Overflow eats the trailing `)`, add it to the URL and it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That program runs without error on my system.

At a guess, the library that is being linked into the executable by ld.so is the wrong one for the X11 server.

try `ldd <your program>` and look for the line for libGL.so, e.g.:

```
    libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/nvidia-current/libGL.so.1 (0x00007f9d4bdf5000)
```

If that library is not the correct library for your system, anything could happen.  An X11 "invalid opcode" error is more than likely.

Also, use [GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net/).  It takes care of details like locating GL calls.