# OpenGL 4. X Error of failed request: BadAlloc (insufficient resources for operation)

Tags: c, opengl-4

I have a one problem when I try compile a program in OpenGL 4. The trouble is the next:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadAlloc (insufficient resources for operation)
   Major opcode of failed request:  136 (GLX)
   Minor opcode of failed request:  34 ()
   Serial number of failed request:  40
   Current serial number in output stream:  41
```

I'm use Debian Wheezy.

The Code is  The OpenGL Book
http://openglbook-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Chapter%201/

Why is this?.

What can be the possible solutions?

The information you need, please ask for it.

Thanks very much for your answers.

Comment: How are you compiling? Can you show some more surrounding output?

Comment: Yes, I'm compiling the following way:

 `gcc -o chapter Chapter1.c -lGL -lglut` 

The ouput is the same above, no show more

Comment: A quick Google suggests to look at [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1762103).

Comment: Thanks,but not Works. Other options?.

Comment: Not really. Perhaps the answere [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10061248/707650) helps?

Comment: How I  know that is the opcode correct?, should exactly `(0x00007f9d4bdf5000)` or with wich I should compare the opcode? . This is the answer when I run the command `ldd` show the following: `libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 (0xb7681000)`

Comment: And you are on a 32bit system?

Comment: yes, there is a problem?, why?.

Comment: If you were on 64bit, that would definitely be the incorrect library. Now, I'm not sure. I do find it odd that that the library lives in a subdirectory `i386-linux-gnu`, and not just in `/usr/lib/` (or `/usr/lib32/`). See if you can find more `libGL` libraries on your system. And if you have an NVidia graphics card, probably make sure to use those libraries instead.

Comment: when I run the command:                                       `find /usr/lib/ -iname "libGL.so.1" -exec ls -latd {} \;` </br>  The  ouput is the folowing:   `/usr/lib/mesa-diverted/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 -> libGL.so.1.2    
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/nvidia/current/libGL.so.1 -> libGL.so.304.48 
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/nvidia/libGL.so.1 -> /etc/alternatives/nvidia--libGL.so.1-i386-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 -> /etc/alternatives/glx--libGL.so.1-i386-linux-gnu`  **how to use libraries Nvidia?**

Comment: To compile with libraries in a different directory: `gcc -o chapter Chapter1.c -lGL -lglut -L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/nvidia`. When running the program, make sure your library path is set to that directory as well: `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/nvidia` in bash. The amount of found libraries is kind-of scary...